# Scrape 160.000 pages - too slow

Tags: python, urllib2

I have a file with more than 160.000 urls, of which pages I want to scrape some information. The script looks roughly like this:

```
htmlfile = urllib2.urlopen(line)
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
regexName = '"></a>(.+?)</dd><dt>'
patternName = re.compile(regexName)
name = re.findall(patternName,htmltext)
if name:
   text = name[0]
else:
   text = 'unknown'

nf.write(text)
```

Which works, but very, very slow. It would take more than four days to scrape all 160.000 pages. Any suggestions to speed it up?

Comment: Use multithreading or an asynchronous http requests library like [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests)

Comment: Or use scrappy. http://scrapy.org/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but I have no idea how to use grequetsts or scrapy. I'm a huge python newbie...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some advice on your code:

When you compile the regex pattern, make sure you also use the compiled object. And avoid compiling your regex in each processing loop.

```
pattern = re.compile('"></a>(.+?)</dd><dt>')
# ...
links = pattern.findall(html)
```

If you want to avoid using other frameworks, the best solution to speed things up it so use the **standard threading library** in order to get **multiple HTTP connections going in parallel**.

Something like this:

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

import urllib2
import re

# Work queue where you push the URLs onto - size 100
url_queue = Queue(10)
pattern = re.compile('"></a>(.+?)</dd><dt>')

def worker():
    '''Gets the next url from the queue and processes it'''
    while True:
        url = url_queue.get()
        print url
        html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        print html[:10]
        links = pattern.findall(html)
        if len(links) > 0:
            print links
        url_queue.task_done()

# Start a pool of 20 workers
for i in xrange(20):
     t = Thread(target=worker)
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()

# Change this to read your links and queue them for processing
for url in xrange(100):
    url_queue.put("http://www.ravn.co.uk")

# Block until everything is finished.
url_queue.join()
```